# Can't reach Sonatype Nexus OSS Repository inside LAN

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype

I've a machine running Nexus OSS Repository (version 3.15.1-01) on port 8081 in my intranet . I can ping this machine through it's IP, I've even Jenkins running on port 8080 and can reach it just fine through any internet browser. However, when I try to reach Nexus remotely on 8081, I get only timeouts.

I've configured the http/https proxy on Nexus (we've a corporate proxy) and it can download artifacts from online repos with no issue, and I can access the running server physically on the machine through localhost or 127.0.0.1 on port 8081.

It is like some configuration is blocking the remote access to Nexus, but I've failed to find this sort of configuration in the app or documentation (aside from the checkbox to "accept incoming requests" inside repo config, which is enabled). Any clues on what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure your corporate proxy is configured correctly? https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1):

Well, after hours of searching: Apparently the default access URL right after you install Nexus in your server depends on god knows what; quoting the documentation:

> While the documentation uses localhost throughout, you may need to use the IP Loopback Address of 127.0.0.1, the IP address or the DNS hostname assigned to the machine running the repository manager.

It never says what determines the URL you have to use or where you can change it. What it does say though, is how to change the port:

> The default value for the HTTP port used to access the repository manager user interface and resources is 8081. Therefore the user interface would be available at  http://localhost:8081/. To change or update the port, locate the line application-port=8081 in $data-dir/etc/nexus.properties, then edit the number.

Checking this file, it also has an application-host field in which you can set the IP of the server, and if you do so you can access through this IP both physically and remotelly, while the default (in my case localhost) didn't allow for remote access.

Gonna ask them to make this part of the documentation a bit more clear, hope it can help someone meanwhile.

Comment: There is no "default access URL" in Nexus, if you can reach it via the network it will work, regardless of the host name/address used.  Your problem sounds like a network problem, not a Nexus issue.

Comment: @Jorge, The address at which you can reach NXRM, or any other app, can not be chosen by the app or its configuration. This is determined by your network configuration. It sounds as if you are running behind a reverse proxy, so this might be of help: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy . The `application-host` allows you to bind socket listeners to a specific host if that's what you're after. If you would share with us more about your network configuration and what would you like to achieve we can try to work it out together.

Comment: @Dawid well not the address but the host as you say, and indeed changing the host to the static IP of the machine worked well, and I can now access the repo remotelly. This is what I was trying to achieve, so doing that solved my issue. However if you would be so kind, I'd love to hear from you on why could this be working for me (I've a corporate forward proxy, not a reverse proxy, plus the machine running nexus is in the same intranet of the client). Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: It could be that you were using a hostname that's not resolvable to any IP. if you have bound the NXRM to some IP then maybe the hostname you used resolves to a different IP. Try some simple troubleshooting, run `ping`, `nslookup` and `telnet` against the hostname you want to use both from your NXRM box and your developer machine. Also, please check your `nexus.log` for a line similar to `Started ServerConnector@53a59726{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}` to check where is it listening for connections.

Comment: @Jorge.V Can you please tell me how other users can remotely use my library?  i have uploaded the aar and pom to the maven-releases after that what I need to do it's not clearly mentioned in their documentation.